Unable to enable Performance Insights on Amazon RDS db.t3.small instance
I recently upgraded my Amazon RDS instance from db.t2.micro to db.t3.small. After the upgrade, I also activated the performance_schema parameter in the associated parameter group because I've read somewhere that this config could helps enable Performance Insights. However, the option to configure Performance Insights does not appear when I go to the "Modify" tab of my database instance.
DB is running on MySQL 8.0.35 and here's a summary of what I have done so far:

Upgraded from db.t2.micro to db.t3.small.
Enabled performance_schema by setting it to 1 in the parameter group.
Verified that performance_schema is active by checking the current
configuration.
Enhanced Monitoring is already activated too.

Despite these steps, when I check the configurations it shows Performance Insights turned off but the option to enable or configure Performance Insights is still missing in the "Modify" tab.
For reference, I found a YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92UNEOcBW_g) where someone uses a similar db.t3.small instance (but with PostgreSQL) and successfully enables and accesses Performance Insights. This makes me wonder if there might be specific configurations or steps that I'm missing for my setup.
Additionally, I have read conflicting information regarding the availability of Performance Insights. Some sources suggest that it is only available starting from db.t3.medium while others indicate that it should be available from db.t3.small.
Note: when I enter the monitoring tab of the database, AWS itself suggests enabling Performance Insights.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I found a page entitled "Amazon RDS DB engine, Region, and instance class support for Performance Insights". According to the first table on that page (under the column "Instance class restrictions" in the "RDS for MySQL" row):

Performance Insights isn't supported for the following instance classes:

db.t2.micro
db.t2.small
db.t3.micro
db.t3.small (Your Current Instance Class)
db.t4g.micro
db.t4g.small


This was also expressed on this Chinese page

You could turn it on if you do not satisfy below
8.0.17 and higher 8.0 versions, version 5.7.22 and higher 5.7 versions, and version 5.6.41 and higher 5.6 versions.
Not supported on the following DB instance classes: db.t2.micro,
db.t2.small, db.t3.micro, and db.t3.small (Your Current Instance Class).

In light of this, I highly recommend upgrading to db.t3.medium

For Aurora instances, t2 and t3 series, performance insights is not supported.

Performance Insights has the following engine class restrictions:
db.t2 – Not supported
db.t3 – Not supported
db.t4g.micro and db.t4g.small – Not supported

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.Overview.Engines.html
If you want to enable performance insights for a medium instance you will need to choose t4g series.
